# Failed to get game data from the server

Tags: pokemon-go

What does "Failed to get game data from the server" mean? Some people say I got a ban but why?
I never use any cheat or hacks. Can you give me an answer?

Comment: It's the usual error when you were banned. Without any other information, we can't really tell anything else. For instance: What level are you?
But first you should try to write proper sentences. Here you souldn't use abbreveations.

Comment: Banhammer has spoken.

Answer (score 2):

This message means your account has been banned. You should receive an email from Niantic later this week explaining the reason behind the ban and if it is a permanent ban or temporary ban. You can appeal the ban should you wish to do so.

Answer (score -2):

No, It does't means that you are ban by the company.The message simply says that at that instant it was not possible to fetch data from server.

There will be problem in connection with Server or it might be possible that